# How can i update my URL when im managing my sites via AJAX?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, url

Im loading the content of my sites via ajax&jquery into a area of the "main" page, so loading goes faster. but the problem is that with that method im getting serious SEO problems, because the URL is not getting updated. and search engines only index the homepage not all the other content too. So how can i update the URL of the site everytime when im loading new content? How can i let the page load the content needed when a updated URL is given?

you can view the whole sourcecode here: http://boxcomp.111mb.de/luxus/html8

can you maybe directly suggest me what i should add to existing jquery code? you can find it on top of the index.html file.

sorry for the "mess"

thank you very much!

Comment: see https://developers.google.com/webmasters/ajax-crawling/ for Google's practices

Answer (score 2):

All current browsers, including IE10+, do support [HTML5 History API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Manipulating_the_browser_history#Adding_and_modifying_history_entries) that allows to alter URL address without reloading page. For older browsers, you can just not use Ajax.

Search engines should not be affected by Ajax at all. They should see regular static links with regular `href` attributes.

Answer (score 0):

I have to disappoint you.

You can't change the browser's url without reloading the page.
The only thing you can do is add anchors to the page:

```
index.html -> index.html#page1
```

But I think, these are not really relevant for search engines.

So you have to decide: either SEO or Ajax - but both is not possible...

Comment: This is not entirely true. Luckily Google found a solution using #! instead of the regular #. See https://developers.google.com/webmasters/ajax-crawling/docs/getting-started